# Pandas 'color=[]' only displaying first color value for all bars in chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter

I'm using Pandas 1.1.4 trying to graph a dataframe in Jupyter, with the bar colors a certain color depending on the value of a column.

```
col = []
for count in df_count.values:
    val = [1, 3, 6]
    colors = ['r', 'g', 'b']
    for i in range(len(val)):
        if count == val[i]:
            col.append(colour[i])
```

col output:

```
['r', 'r', 'g', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'g']
```

This should create a bar chart with the bars colored as indicated in the above list.

```
df_count.plot.barh(figsize=(10, 5), color=col, legend=False)
```

However this doesn't seem to be the case, as the entire chart takes on the colors of the first value in the list, 'r'. Is there something i'm missing here?

[Screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sd9Ei.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the answer almost immediately after posting this question, but I will leave it up with a solution in-case anyone comes across this issue.

```
df_count.plot.barh(figsize=(10, 5), color=[col], legend=False)
```

Comment: this solution doesn't mean much without seeing what kind the values if `df_count` is